# Concatenate Long SMSes sent through Transactional API

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, transactional-messaging-api

During Covid our users have been sending really long text messages via transactional SMSes regarding rules and regulations with 2k+, 3k+,4k+ characters.Is there a hard limit to what we can send? .Whats the best approach to handle those smses?Is shortening our text messages only solution?we saw some 2600 characters being delivered as well.Is there a way to handle concatenation with transactional API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any specific hard limits on sms message lengths however be aware that any message that exceeds 160 characters will be be split into multiple messages and order of delivery cannot necessarily be guaranteed.

Some markets and carriers support [message concatenation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_message_concatenation.htm&type=5) which allows multi-segment messages to appear on the phone as one message.

In situations where the message content drastically exceeds the SMS protocol limit, I typically advise different approaches to conveying the message. Perhaps the content is better served in an email if email is available or potentially craft a shorter language with a link to the longer message in an external site or CloudPage to hopefully provide a better user experience.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Cates Implemented it with Cloud page

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use transactional API SMS (/messaging/v1/sms/messages/{{$guid}}) if your SMS message exceeds 160 char(s)

You will need to use postMessageContact Send (/sms/v1/messageContact/{id}/send) https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postMessageContactSend.html

along with Outbound - API Triggered Template in Mobile Connect and have the concatenate option enabled = TRUE (if your BU has concatenate option enabled)

Comment: There's no such limit at the API level. 160 chars is an older max for a message transmitted over GSM. Nowadays most carriers and SMS aggregators fronting them are quite a bit more sophisticated, they will segment the message,